# Ubuntu 20.04: Permanently disable a service start at boot

Tags: ubuntu, services, cups, avahi, mdns

I am using Ubuntu 20.04. I have tried to stop and disable the avahi-daemon as below:

```
$ sudo systemctl stop avahi-daemon.service
$ sudo systemctl disable --now avahi-daemon.socket
$ sudo systemctl disable --now avahi-daemon.service
```

However, the service restarts after I reboot.

I would also like to stop `cups` service from starting at boot and tried the above, but without luck!

How to disable a service start at boot in Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: Does `systemctl mask` work?

Comment: @NasirRiley, Yes it does. I don't know why they change the way a service is handled every few years. You should post this as an answer which should help many like me. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`systemctl disable` works most of the time but to be sure, use `systemctl mask`.

What this does is to link the unit files to `/dev/null` which effectively causes any start operation or command to fail.

You can see more on this in the `man` page.